# Logstash how to get inputs from .CSV file?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I have just recently started learning Logstash (and the ELK stack) but I have been struggling to get inputs from a csv file in Logstash (the csv file is in the same directory as the .conf file).

I just have a very simple script. My script is as follows:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:\elastic\logstash-8.3.2\config\in.csv"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => ";"
        columns => ["Name","Deposit","Month"]
    }
    mutate {
        convert => {
            "Deposit" => "integer"
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }

    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "randomname"
    }
}
```

The csv file is ";" seperated and is like this line by line (random values):

```
Name;Number;Month
Name;Number;Month
Name;Number;Month
Name;Number;Month
Name;Number;Month
Name;Number;Month
Name;Number;Month
```

When I run Logstash, there seems to be no errors but I don't see any inputs going to the console and/or ElasticSearch. Why would this be the case? Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my .conf file to the following and it seems to work.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/elastic/logstash-8.3.2/config/in.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NULL"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => ";"
        columns => ["name","deposit","month"]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        index => "randomname"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File input plugin in logstash will store file at path.data location in logstash.yml. so modify the location of the file pointer to Null device if you are reading from same file on each run.

Comment: So do I write `path.data: "NULL"` in the logstash.yml file (I use Windows 10)?

Comment: No. by default path.data will be "Data" folder inside installation directory. So your sincedb file will inside "data\plugins\inputs". In your case if you wish to re-run the logstash configuration against same input file, just modify "sincedb_path =>" in config file to "NULL" else point to appropriate file location